# How can I update the firmware on a Virgin Superhub?

Tags: networking, router

A long time ago, I was with Virgin Media for my Internet. Since then, I have moved on, but as I was never asked to return the router, I still have it, so I have integrated it into my (non-Virgin) network as a range extender.

When I was going through it, I noticed that the current Firmware (R30) is dated at September 2011. I have searched Google to see if it can be updated, but all I have found is that it will only upgrade if connected to the Internet via the built-in modem on a Virgin network.

As this is no longer possible, am I able to somehow upgrade the firmware manually?

Comment: Is there a reason you need the firmware updated?

Comment: I have searched for version histories, but I can't find much on the subject. So, it's more of a case of I'd like to instead of I need to